# How does `screen` actually work?

Tags: gnu-screen

I just learned about `screen` and it looks wonderful.

Some questions:

1. How do they actually work?
2. Why are downloads / process not interrupted in screens even though something bad happened?

Comment: May be useful: `echo $TERM` in a screen session prints `screen` as opposed to `xterm` in ordinary bash sessions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Very briefly (it's possible to write several pages on the topic): `screen` *works* by

- setting up a server process that takes over all input/output directly to your terminal,
- starting client processes for each *window* that you create, and
- connecting the server and clients as they are started using a *pseudo-terminal* connection (a feature of the operating system).

Once a client (window) is created, it is isolated from the other clients.  It communicates via the pseudo-terminal connection to the server process, which updates the terminal.  The server keeps track of what should be shown on the terminal in a given window, providing you with the ability to switch between windows.  The clients run without knowing if `screen` is currently displaying their information.

Comment: clear and fast +1