# Running a pseudoterminal inside a pseudoterminal

Tags: terminal, tty, pty

I'm trying to understand how the programs like `screen` and `script` control I/O.

My knowledge of terminal, tty etc. comes from reading the ['tty demystified'](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) article, and all the SE answers I could find. So from what I understand, roughly the interactions between components work as follows:

`Console(Keyboard+Screen) ---- xterm(pty master)  ----- tty line discipline ---- bash/other programs(pty slave)`

where the line discipline is in the kernel, and xterm and bash run in the userspace.

1. Is this correct?

Now, when we consider programs like [`screen`](https://ss64.com/bash/screen.html), [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html), they are userspace programs that **run in a terminal**(the existing xterm), yet are able to control I/O to/from other programs. The article mentions that this is becuase they run another pseudoterminal inside xterm(the existing pseudoterminal).

2. Does that mean that they open up a new `pty` master - slave pair, control the master end of this new pair, and all the processes launched from them run on the new `pty` slave? For example each time I start a new 'screen', and run the `tty` command, it shows me a diffrent `/dev/pts/x`. Does `script` also run in a similar way?
3. Finally can somebody point me to any article/book where I can get a little more detail on this stuff(Haven't been able to find anything)?

I'd also like to reference [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370795/how-does-screen-actually-work) answer, though it is very brief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

① Yes, xterm and bash run in userspace. As do screen and script.

② Yep, that's correct. Screen basically is a terminal emulator, just like XTerm. Except of course XTerm outputs commands to the X11 server to display the terminal, whereas screen outputs control sequences & text to a another terminal (which can be a terminal emulator or an actual terminal).

③ The best detail on how those programs work is probably the source code. Questions about them are welcome here, of course, or code questions are welcome on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).